# SSL realization for NSURLSession

Tags: java, android, ios, security, ssl

I have a big problem with in my app. 
I had java implementation, but i need to do the same for iOS app by using Security.framework an NSURLSession, and i dont know how. It will be great if u help me.

Java:

```
        // get our trusted CA from resources
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        int caResId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("cert_ca", "raw", context.getPackageName());
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(context.getResources().openRawResource(caResId));
        String alias = cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName();
        // create empty trust store with only our CA
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null);
        trustStore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
        // create TrustManagers based on our trust store
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        tmf.init(trustStore);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        // get our client certificate from resources
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        String pass = context.getResources().getString(R.string.pass);
        int clientResId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("cert_client", "raw", context.getPackageName());
        keyStore.load(context.getResources().openRawResource(clientResId), pass.toCharArray());
        // create KeyManagers based on our key store 
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        kmf.init(keyStore, pass.toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

        // create SSL context
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);

        URL requestedUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)requestedUrl.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1500); // ?
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1500); // ?
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        String responseMessage = urlConnection.getResponseMessage();

        urlConnection.disconnect();
```

Solve it by following code (It can be helpful for someone):

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session didReceiveChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
if ([self shouldTrustProtectionSpace:challenge.protectionSpace]) {
    [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
} else {
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mobile_client (1)" ofType:@"pfx"];
    NSData *p12data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    CFDataRef inP12data = (__bridge CFDataRef)p12data;

    SecIdentityRef myIdentity;
    SecTrustRef myTrust;
    extractIdentityAndTrust(inP12data, &myIdentity, &myTrust);

    SecCertificateRef myCertificate;
    SecIdentityCopyCertificate(myIdentity, &myCertificate);
    const void *certs[] = { myCertificate };
    CFArrayRef certsArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, certs, 1, NULL);

    NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:myIdentity certificates:(__bridge NSArray*)certsArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

    [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
}

}
OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inP12data, SecIdentityRef *identity, SecTrustRef *trust)
{
OSStatus securityError = errSecSuccess;

CFStringRef password = CFSTR("123");
const void *keys[] = { kSecImportExportPassphrase };
const void *values[] = { password };

CFDictionaryRef options = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values, 1, NULL, NULL);

CFArrayRef items = CFArrayCreate(NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
securityError = SecPKCS12Import(inP12data, options, &items);

if (securityError == 0) {
    CFDictionaryRef myIdentityAndTrust = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(items, 0);
    const void *tempIdentity = NULL;
    tempIdentity = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemIdentity);
    *identity = (SecIdentityRef)tempIdentity;
    const void *tempTrust = NULL;
    tempTrust = CFDictionaryGetValue(myIdentityAndTrust, kSecImportItemTrust);
    *trust = (SecTrustRef)tempTrust;
}

if (options) {
    CFRelease(options);
}

return securityError;
}

- (BOOL)shouldTrustProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
  // Load up the bundled certificate.
  NSString *certPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mobile_ca" ofType:@"der"];
  NSData *certData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:certPath];
  SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)(certData));

  SecTrustRef serverTrust = protectionSpace.serverTrust;

  CFArrayRef certArrayRef = CFArrayCreate(NULL, (void *)&cert, 1, NULL);
  SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, certArrayRef);

  SecTrustResultType trustResult;
  SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);

  return  trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified;}
```